# Get saved (non commited) entities with a criteria from session cache in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, session, caching, criteria

I'm trying to break the question down to something simple.

I use nhibernate to get a list of entities via a criteria call. After that I'll update some entites and add one entity which I save (session.SaveOrUpdate(entity)).
When I get a list with a criteria again I do get the entities that were changed (with changed values) in my list but not the entity I added. I read that the criteria doesn't use the session cash but "will always result in a SQL query / call to the DB".
Well, somehow the entities that I changed are from the session cache (I didn't commit yet and nothing has been written to the database) but the Criteria doesn't "find" my newly added entity.
Is it possible to make the Criteria get all entities from the cache (i know the added entity is there cause i can check the keys in the statistics-entitykeys list)?

P.s.:It's somehow strange that I can load a list of entities, ADD AND SAVE some, get the "whole list" again and still only get the ones that were in there the first time. Do I really need to commit to get the full list?

P.s.s: I don't want to use the second level cache cause that would mean i commit changes made in another session too when I "commit", right?

Comment: Can you tell why you want to do this? Maybe someone has a good solution for the thing you are trying to do in a different way than you suggest.

Comment: basically it's like my app has different modules for different tasks and every task has it's own session (e.g. a task like editing customer data). the user may create a new customer and fill in the forms. when he opens the form I create a new customer and save it to the session, then the user edits it. the entities itself are  just committed when the user saves his changes. now i have the option on the same form to connect a customer to another customer and when the user clicks the button for this option i open up a new form (same session-it's just a dialog) with a list of customers from the

Comment: database which unfortunately doesn't include customers that have been created but not committed (and i don't always want to commit when the user changes customers but only when he SAVES his changes)

Answer (score 1):

`Flush` your changes and you'll see the newly added entity in the list. You don't have to `Commit`, but Criteria returns the results of a SQL query, it doesn't magically go through the caches retrieving entities that *might be* included in the results,

Comment: okay. I tried that and then i get the problem, that after the commit flush the used tables are locked till either a commit or a rollback. you are right that the criterias return the correct results including the new entities but locking whole tables will the user decides to save or not isn't really an option.

Comment: You never mentioned this was part of an interactive windows client workflow, nor that there was an intermediate step.

Comment: sorry. i would have voted your answer up but i don't have enough reputation to do that. seems like what i am trying to do isn't really supported that easily and i will have to manage non-comitted entities on my own.